# Gimp script does not have permission to write a jpeg file

Tags: macos, permissions, script, gimp

I'm trying to run a GIMP script to perform Error Level Analysis.
I've downloaded the script (a `.scm file) from [here](https://sites.google.com/site/elsamuko/forensics/ela).

It does show up in the menu (`Image -> Error Level Analysis`), shows a dialog, but then stops because of the following two errors (they show up simultaneously):

[image]
[image]

From other forum posts I understood that it might need executable permission.
Hence I run the command `chmod u+x` on the `.scm` file. This did not solve the issue.
Also running GIMP as an admin with `sudo open /Applications/GIMP.app` did not change anything.

How can I give this script write permission in GIMP 2.8.10 on Mac OS 10.8.5?

Comment: GIMP scripts do not need executable permission. In this case, it is likely that a temporary image is written to a place where you do not have write permission - the script doesn't make use of the configured temp directory, most likely.